# Visual Basic shell32.shell

Tags: vb.net, shell32

For more than likely a very obvious reason when I try build or run my program it breaks on this function below:

```
Public Function GetLnkTarget(lnkPath As String) As String
    Dim shl = New Shell32.Shell()
    lnkPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(lnkPath)
    Dim dir = shl.[NameSpace](System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(lnkPath))
    Dim itm = dir.Items().Item(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(lnkPath))
    Dim lnk = DirectCast(itm.GetLink, Shell32.ShellLinkObject)

    Try
        Return lnk.Target.Path
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

The error I get is:

> System.InvalidCastException
>   HResult=0x80004002
>   Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface     type 'Shell32.Shell'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{286E6F1B-7113-4355-9562-96B7E9D64C54}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>   Source=Administrator Tools

Any feedback/ideas on how I can proceed with this would be great!

Comment: You'll get this exception when this code runs on a worker thread.  An STA thread is required.

Comment: @HansPassant Did this get added at some point after 2014? I just had to do a minor mod to an old app in VS2010 (last compiled in 2014) and the new exe (still compiled on a Win 7 OS) is giving me this error. There's nothing in the code related to STAThread.